# Consuming a "Page Method" from outside of the ASP.NET Page

Tags: asp.net, pagemethods

I have a asp.net web app with some in page web service methods.  It is not an asmx page, just Default.aspx.  For example:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string SignUp(UserCredential userCredential)
    {
    }
```

I have no problem consuming this web service using jquery embeded in the Default.aspx page.  Now I want to consume this web method in a console program for example.  When I add the web reference to the console program, it said:  The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.

How can I consume this in page web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot consume that page method from outside of the page. You need a separate service for that.

You should do the following:

1. Create a separate WCF service project to hold the new service
2. Extract the guts of your page method into a similar service method in your new service project
3. Test the new service and make it work
4. In your ASP.NET project, use "Add Service Reference" to permit you to reference the new service
5. Call the new service from inside of the page method

Comment: Just to clarify, you can call ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods from different .aspx pages via jQuery, but for your console application scenario creating a service is the way to go.

Comment: @KarlAnderson: thanks for the clarification. I didn't know they could even be called from a different page. I've never used them. I guess the page is part of the URL: `http://something/somewhere/MyPage.aspx/MyMethod?params` or something like that.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - yes, the page is part of the URL and since ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods are static they do not need the page instance to work. ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods are a hidden feature of ASP.NET and a lot of people do not use them (no offense).

Comment: @KarlAnderson: no offense taken. I've just never been certain that page methods are worth the confusion that they cause. That, plus the fact that everyone who uses them is dependent on the same technology as ASMX, which is a legacy technology.

Answer (score 1):

Another option you have is to use the ASP.NET Web API to create your service methods and then consume them in a console application, like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:9000/");

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        // Call Web API methods here
    }
}
```

Read [Calling a Web API From a .NET Client](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) for a tutorial on consuming an ASP.NET Web API service from a C# console application.